# ReactJS - Get Height of an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the Height of an element after React renders that element?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
<!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
<p>
jnknwqkjnkj<br>
jhiwhiw (this is 36px height)
</p>
</div>
```

**ReactJS**

```
var DivSize = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    let elHeight = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight
    return <div className="test">Size: <b>{elHeight}px</b> but it should be 18px after the render</div>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <DivSize />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**RESULT**

```
Size: 36px but it should be 18px after the render
```

It's calculating the container height before the render (36px). I want to get the height after the render. The right result should be 18px in this case. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29800/)

Comment: This is not a react question but rather a Javascript and DOM question. You should try to figure out which DOM event you should use to find the final height of your element. In the event handler, you can use `setState` to assign the height value to a state variable.

Comment: Nowadays, I highly recommend just using react-use's useMeasure hook instead to do this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/29802/) fiddle (actually updated your's)

You need to hook into `componentDidMount` which is run after render method. There, you get actual height of element.

```js
var DivSize = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
    return { state: 0 };
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    const height = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight;
    this.setState({ height });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
        <div className="test">
        Size: <b>{this.state.height}px</b> but it should be 18px after the render
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <DivSize />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
<p>
jnknwqkjnkj<br>
jhiwhiw (this is 36px height)
</p>
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Comment: not correct. see Paul Vincent Beigang's answer below

Comment: IMHO, a component should not know the name of its container

Comment: This is wrong! Not a good practice. See other proposed solutions.

Answer (score 243):

For those who are interested in using `react hooks`, this might help you get started.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default () => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
  const ref = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight)
  })

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {height}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - it helped me get started.  2 questions though:

(1) For these layout-measuring tasks, should we use `useLayoutEffect` instead of `useEffect`?  The docs seem to indicate that we should.  See the "tip" section here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#detailed-explanation

(2) For these cases where we just need a reference to a child element, should we use `useRef` instead of `createRef`?  The docs seem to indicate the `useRef` is more appropriate for this use case.  See:  https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: I just implemented a solution that uses the two items I'm suggesting.  They seem to work well, but you may know of some downsides to these choices?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JasonFrank Good questions. 1) Both useEffect and useLayoutEffect will be fired after layout and paint. However, useLayoutEffect will fire synchronously before the next paint. I'd say if you really need visual consistency then use useLayoutEffect, otherwise, useEffect should suffice. 2) You're right about that! In a functional component createRef will create a new ref every time the component is being rendered. Using useRef is the better option. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Comment: This helped me understand how to use a ref with hooks. I ended up going with `useLayoutEffect` after reading the other comments here. Seems to work well. :)

Comment: I was setting dimensions of my component `useEffect(() => setDimensions({width: popup.current.clientWidth, height: popup.current.clientHeight}))`, and my IDE (WebStorm) suggested me this: *ESLint: React Hook useEffect contains a call to 'setDimensions'. Without a list of dependencies, this can lead to an infinite chain of updates. To fix this, pass [] as a second argument to the useEffect Hook. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)*, so pass `[]` as second argument to your `useEffect`

Comment: I have a similar scenario but I am calling `setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight)` from a child component and applying the `height` to a sibling component as paddingTop like so, `<main style={{ paddingTop: height }} >`. Now to check if it works realtime I also added this line in useEffect of Child component `setTimeout(() => {
      ref.current.style.height = "50px"
    }, 2000)`. This does update the value of `height` state in parent component but the `paddingTop` is still the previous value and doesn't update?

Comment: @faia20 you may want to select this more modern answer.

Comment: @AkshdeepSingh yes, passing array argument stop the loop but, at least in my case does not really make the task: it run just once. In fact it is tricky and simple at the same time: pass an array of variables that would be checked for changes (no element, nothing changes), In my case, I use `let myself = useRef(null);` then I pass the array `[myself.current, myself.current?myself.current.clientHeight:0]`
I want to know when clientHeight change, it may be strange, but it works this way.

Comment: Thank you! Ctrl + F for "useRef" got me here. knew it would be clean and concise

Comment: I'm following a similar pattern as described here however i get an error cannot read property clientHeight of null, what could be the problem?

Comment: this leads to warning though: "ESLint: React Hook useEffect contains a call to 'setDimensions'. Without a list of dependencies, this can lead to an infinite chain of updates."

Answer (score 197):

Following is an up to date ES6 example using a [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Remember that we have to use a [React class component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) since we need to access the Lifecycle method `componentDidMount()` because we can only determine the height of an element after it is rendered in the DOM.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {render} from 'react-dom'

class DivSize extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      height: 0
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const height = this.divElement.clientHeight;
    this.setState({ height });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        className="test"
        ref={ (divElement) => { this.divElement = divElement } }
      >
        Size: <b>{this.state.height}px</b> but it should be 18px after the render
      </div>
    )
  }
}

render(<DivSize />, document.querySelector('#container'))
```

You can find the running example here: https://codepen.io/bassgang/pen/povzjKw

Comment: This works but I am getting several eslint errors for Airbnb styleguide: `<div ref={ divElement => this.divElement = divElement}>{children}</div>` throws "[eslint] Arrow function should not return assignment. (no-return-assign)" and `this.setState({ height });` throws "[eslint] Do not use setState in componentDidMount (react/no-did-mount-set-state)". Anyone got a styleguide-compliant solution?

Comment: Wrap the assignment in braces  so that it behaves as a function (rather than an expression), like this `ref={ divElement => {this.divElement = divElement}}`

Comment: This sould be the accepted answer :) Besides, if you want to get the size of the element after the element is updated, you can use the method `componentDidUpdate` as well.

Comment: is there an alternative to calling this.setState() in componentDidMount with this example?

Comment: Good solution. But won't work for responsive designs. If header height was 50px for desktop, and user shrinks the window size, and now height becomes 100px, this solution won't take the updated height. They need to refresh the page to get the changed effects.

Comment: @TheCoder to detect window resize: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661790/reactjs-get-rendered-component-height

Comment: On mobile, this.divElement.clientHeight returns 0.  Does anyone know how to resolve this on mobile?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of undefined ---for me

Answer (score 33):

Instead of using `document.getElementById(...)`, a better (up to date) solution is to use the React [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook that stores a reference to the component/element, combined with a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook, which fires at component renders.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

export default App = () => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setHeight(elementRef.current.clientHeight);
  }, []); //empty dependency array so it only runs once at render

  return (
    <div ref={elementRef}>
      {height}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 15):

it might show zero. setTimeout helps to get the correct value and update the state.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'
    
    export default () => {
      const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
      const ref= useRef(null)
    
      useEffect(() => {
       if(ref.current.clientHeight){
         setTimeout(() => {
           setHeight(ref.current.clientHeight) 
         }, 1000)
       }
      })
    
      return (
        <div ref={ref}>
          {height}
        </div>
      )
    }
```

Comment: there is another solution using `onreadystatechange`, which also works. I have a ref to a `<canvas>` element that I was trying to get the correct height and both `setTimeout(()=>{}, 0)` and `document.onreadystatechange(()=>{})` helped get the correct height.

Comment: What is `elemRef`?

Comment: should be ref @Ziyuan

Comment: FWIW it's really OK to edit your answer to resolve that `elemRef` issue and make it a better answer

Answer (score 12):

You would also want to use refs on the element instead of using `document.getElementById`, it's just a slightly more robust thing.

Comment: @doublejosh basically you are right but what to do if you need to mixup for example `angularJs` and `react` while migrating from one to the other? There are cases where a direct DOM manipulation is really needed

Answer (score 9):

My 2020's (or 2019) answer

```
import React, {Component, useRef, useLayoutEffect} from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { Toast, ToastBody, ToastHeader } from 'reactstrap';

import {WidgetHead} from './WidgetHead';

export const Widget = ({title, toggle, reload, children, width, name}) => {
    let myself = useRef(null);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useLayoutEffect(()=>{
        if (myself.current) {
            const height = myself.current.clientHeight
            dispatch({type:'GRID_WIDGET_HEIGHT', widget:name, height})
        }
    }, [myself.current, myself.current?myself.current.clientHeight:0])

    return (
        <Toast innerRef={myself}>
            <WidgetHead title={title}
                toggle={toggle}
                reload={reload} />
            <ToastBody>
            {children}
            </ToastBody>
        </Toast>
    )
}
```

let use your imagination for what is missing here (WidgetHead), `reactstrap` is something you can find on npm: replace `innerRef` with `ref` for a legacy dom element (say a `<div>`).

### useEffect or useLayoutEffect

The last is said to be synchronous for changes

### `useLayoutEffect` (or `useEffect`) second argument

Second argument is an array, and it is checked before executing the function in the first argument.

I used

> [myself.current, myself.current?myself.current.clientHeight:0]

because myself.current is null before rendering, and that is a good thing not to check, the second parameter at the end `myself.current.clientHeight` is what I want to check for changes.

### what I am solving here (or trying to solve)

I am solving here the problem of widget on a grid that change its height by their own will, and the grid system should be *elastic enough* to react ( https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout ).

Comment: great answer, but would have benefited from simpler example. Basically whiteknight's answer but with `useLayoutEffect` and actual div to tie the ref to.

Comment: This answer almost works for me, but when I resize my window I do not see the height recalculate.

Comment: @carmenism strange. I thought it was the contrary, it should be calculated on each rerender, but maybe you can force rendering by parameter changes. About the code I can not recall about width passed to Widget component, but maybe that is a way to force re-render the component, so fire useLayoutEffect() and recalc

Answer (score 6):

Using with hooks :

This answer would be helpful if your content dimension changes after loading.

**onreadystatechange** : Occurs when the load state of the data that belongs to an element or a HTML document changes. The onreadystatechange event is fired on a HTML document when the load state of the page's content has changed.

```
import {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
const ref = useRef();
useEffect(() => {
    document.onreadystatechange = () => {
      console.log(ref.current.clientHeight);
    };
  }, []);
```

I was trying to work with a youtube video player embedding whose dimensions may change after loading.

Comment: this answer and the one mentioning use of `setTimeout` are underappreciated. It seems to me `setTimeout(()=>{}, 0)` has the same effect as `document.onreadstatechange = () => {}`. Either way, I need to use either in order to get the correct width/height from `getBoundingRect()`, `clientWidth`, `offsetHeight`, etc. when trying to embed a webgl game built with Unity to a webpage

Comment: @kimbaudi I have seen the wrong width being measured with the setTimeout approach as well, but it seems to happen only occasional. For me, the only stable approch so far was working with onreadystatechange

Answer (score 4):

Here is another one if you need window resize event:

```
class DivSize extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      width: 0,
      height: 0
    }
    this.resizeHandler = this.resizeHandler.bind(this);
  }

  resizeHandler() {
    const width = this.divElement.clientWidth;
    const height = this.divElement.clientHeight;
    this.setState({ width, height });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.resizeHandler();
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.resizeHandler);
  }

  componentWillUnmount(){
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeHandler);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        className="test"
        ref={ (divElement) => { this.divElement = divElement } }
      >
        Size: widht: <b>{this.state.width}px</b>, height: <b>{this.state.height}px</b>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DivSize />, document.querySelector('#container'))
```

[code pen](https://codepen.io/Gfast2/pen/xxwayKg)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `useMeasure` as custom hook (Typescript, SSR, hook):

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';

interface ContainerSize {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

type UseMeasureArgs = () => {
  ref: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  size: ContainerSize;
  windowSize: ContainerSize;
};

const initSize: ContainerSize = { width: 0, height: 0 };

const useMeasure: UseMeasureArgs = () => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  const [size, setSize] = useState<ContainerSize>(initSize);
  const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState<ContainerSize>(initSize);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setSize({ width: ref.current.offsetWidth, height: ref.current.offsetHeight });
    }
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      setWindowSize({
        width: window.innerWidth,
        height: window.innerHeight,
      });
    }
  }, []);

  return { ref, size, windowSize };
};

export default useMeasure;
```

Comment: The typeof window !== 'undefined' is not necessary since useEffect already runs on the client.

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `getBoundingClientRect()` to get height, width.

```js
const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    const element = document.getElementById('element-id');
    if (element) {
      setWidth(element.getBoundingClientRect().width); // or height
    }
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution, in case you want to retrieve the size of a React element synchronously without having to visibly render the element, you can use **[ReactDOMServer](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)** and **[DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser)**.

I use this function to get the height of a my list item renderer when using **[react-window](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window)** (**[react-virtualized](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized)**) instead of having to hardcode the required `itemSize` prop for a **[FixedSizeList](https://react-window.now.sh/#/api/FixedSizeList)**.

**utilities.js:**

```
/**
 * @description Common and reusable functions 
 * 
 * @requires react-dom/server
 * 
 * @public
 * @module
 * 
 */
import ReactDOMServer from "react-dom/server";

/**
 * @description Retrieve the width and/or heigh of a React element without rendering and committing the element to the DOM.
 * 
 * @param {object} elementJSX - The target React element written in JSX.
 * @return {object} 
 * @public
 * @function
 * 
 * @example
 * 
 * const { width, height } = getReactElementSize( <div style={{ width: "20px", height: "40px" }} ...props /> );
 * console.log(`W: ${width}, H: ${height});  // W: 20, H: 40
 * 
 */
const getReactElementSize = (elementJSX) => {

    const elementString = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(elementJSX);
    const elementDocument = new DOMParser().parseFromString(elementString, "text/html");
    const elementNode = elementDocument.getRootNode().body.firstChild;

    const container = document.createElement("div");
    const containerStyle = {

        display: "block",
        position: "absolute",
        boxSizing: "border-box",
        margin: "0",
        padding: "0",
        visibility: "hidden"
    };

    Object.assign(container.style, containerStyle);

    container.appendChild(elementNode);
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    const width = container.clientWidth;
    const height = container.clientHeight;

    container.removeChild(elementNode);
    document.body.removeChild(container);

    return {

        width,
        height
    };
};

/**
 * Export module
 * 
 */
export {

    getReactElementSize
};
```

Comment: Your solution is amazing! It really saved me! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the other answers with React hooks were not updating properly upon resize.

After searching around I found [this blog post](https://medium.com/@eymaslive/react-hooks-useobserve-use-resizeobserver-custom-hook-45ec95ad9844) that gives a working React hook that observes resize events:

The TL;DR is here:

`npm install --save resize-observer-polyfill`

```
// useResizeObserver.js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ResizeObserver from 'resize-observer-polyfill';

const useObserver = ({ callback, element }) => {

  const current = element && element.current;

  const observer = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
      // if we are already observing old element
      if (observer && observer.current && current) {
        observer.current.unobserve(current);
      }
      const resizeObserverOrPolyfill =  ResizeObserver;
      observer.current = new resizeObserverOrPolyfill(callback);
      observe();

      return () => {
        if (observer && observer.current && element &&
           element.current) {
          observer.current.unobserve(element.current);
        }
      };
  }, [current]);

  const observe = () => {
    if (element && element.current && observer.current) {
      observer.current.observe(element.current);
    }
  };

};

useObserver.propTypes = {
  element: PropTypes.object,
  callback: PropTypes.func,
};

export default useObserver;
```

Then an example usage in a component:

```
// shape.js
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import useResizeObserver from 'path/to/useResizeObserver.js';

const Shape = () => {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);
  const svgRef = useRef(null);

  const doHeightAdjustment = () => {
    setHeight(svgRef.current.clientHeight);
  };

  useResizeObserver({callback: doHeightAdjustment, element: svgRef});

  return (
    <div ref={svgRef} style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
      {height}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Shape;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this hook

```
import useMeasure from "react-use-measure";
const [ref, {height}] = useMeasure()
```

the rest of your code

```
<div ref={ref} id="container">
</div>
```

then you can access the height where you want and it is updated every time its size is changing

Answer (score 0):

I found useful npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/element-resize-detector

An optimized cross-browser resize listener for elements.

Can use it with React component or functional component(Specially useful for react hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice reusable hook amended from https://swizec.com/blog/usedimensions-a-react-hook-to-measure-dom-nodes:

```js
import { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react';

function getDimensionObject(node) {
  const rect = node.getBoundingClientRect();

  return {
    width: rect.width,
    height: rect.height,
    top: 'x' in rect ? rect.x : rect.top,
    left: 'y' in rect ? rect.y : rect.left,
    x: 'x' in rect ? rect.x : rect.left,
    y: 'y' in rect ? rect.y : rect.top,
    right: rect.right,
    bottom: rect.bottom
  };
}

export function useDimensions(data = null, liveMeasure = true) {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({});
  const [node, setNode] = useState(null);

  const ref = useCallback(node => {
    setNode(node);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (node) {
      const measure = () =>
        window.requestAnimationFrame(() =>
          setDimensions(getDimensionObject(node))
        );
      measure();

      if (liveMeasure) {
        window.addEventListener('resize', measure);
        window.addEventListener('scroll', measure);

        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('resize', measure);
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', measure);
        };
      }
    }
  }, [node, data]);

  return [ref, dimensions, node];
}
```

To implement:

```js
import { useDimensions } from '../hooks';

// Include data if you want updated dimensions based on a change.
const MyComponent = ({ data }) => {
  const [
    ref,
    { height, width, top, left, x, y, right, bottom }
  ] = useDimensions(data);

  console.log({ height, width, top, left, x, y, right, bottom });

  return (
    <div ref={ref}>
      {data.map(d => (
        <h2>{d.title}</h2>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple hook which waits for the component to first mount before measuring:

```
export function useLayout() {
  const layoutRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
  const [isMounted, setIsMounted] = useState(false)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsMounted(true)
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted || !layoutRef.current) return
    setHeight(layoutRef.current.clientHeight)
    setWidth(layoutRef.current.clientWidth)
  }, [isMounted])

  const isHidden = isMounted && height === 0 && width === 0

  return { isMounted, isHidden, layoutRef, height, width }
}
```

Example usage

```
export function ExampleComponent() {
  const { layoutRef, isHidden, width, height } = useLayout()

  return (
    <div ref={layoutRef}>
      {isHidden ? <Loading /> : <Graph maxWidth={width} maxHeight={height} />}
    </div>
  )
}
```

This fixed the following issue I was having with **recharts**

> console.js:213 The width(0) and height(0) of chart should be greater than 0,
> please check the style of container, or the props width(100%) and height(100%),
> or add a minWidth(550) or minHeight(200) or use aspect(undefined) to control the
> height and width.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the actual `clientHeight` by queuing the `setClientHeight` task into the micro queue in `useEffect`.

```
const [clientHeight, setClientHeight] = useState(0);
const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  queueMicrotask(() => {
    if (containerRef.current) {
      setClientHeight(containerRef.current.clientHeight);
    }
  });
}, []);
```