# Adding ref to Reactstrap Jumbotron causes an error

Tags: reactstrap

I'm trying to read the Jumbotron's height.

In order to do that, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44039401/9479647) answer.

The only difference is that I'm applying the ref to a **Reactstrap Jumbotron**.
So I added this code:

```
  <Jumbotron
    className="test"
    ref={ (divElement) => this.divElement = divElement}
  >
```

The result is this:

> Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts
>   to access this ref will fail.

How should I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue, the problem is that **ReactStrap** uses functional components to render tags so you can't use refs on them. Just convert your jumbotron into a div without using react strap and it will work.

```html
<div className="jumbotron" ref={this.divElement}></div>
```