# How to get div or element height in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get div element in reactJS but I am not able to achieve it . I need some expert to look into my code and resolve my issue or new code snippet would be appreciated .

Thanks

**Code**

```
    this.divElement = React.createRef()

    const height = this.divElement.clientHeight
    this.setState({ height })

     <div
      className="col-2-3"
      ref={(divElement) => {
      this.divElement = divElement
      }}
      >
     </div>
```

Comment: Try setting state inside a `componentDidMount` method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - Get Height of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153599/reactjs-get-height-of-an-element)

Comment: @MaheerAli I am doing it in componentDidmount.

Comment: @WaisKamal no , actually I am following same as mentioned in comment but not able to find solution

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `current` property:

```
this.divElement = React.createRef()

const height = this.divElement.current.clientHeight
this.setState({ height })

 <div
  className="col-2-3"
  ref={this.divElement}
  >
 </div>
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null

Comment: looks like you trying to get the height before the ref is populated try the same in componentDidMount

Comment: Yes, it in componentDidMount