# Change maxHeight of a specific element from React

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I'm using AntD in React and I've built an interface that displays several "Card" components representing kitchen orders.

Each card contains a div that holds the rows with order details. I would like to animate the expansion and collapse of this div when clicking the card action. Pure CSS doesn't allow perfect animation of the height property, but only [maxHeight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css), which should be set equal to the element height to get a perfect animation. Therefore, in React, I need to obtain the scrollHeight of all the divs (i.e., the height including margins, padding, and content space).

When clicking the expand/collapse action of a specific card, I want the maxHeight of that card's div to collapse to maxHeight = 0 or expand to maxHeight = scrollHeight. Below is a piece of code that generates the cards:

```
const ordersDataCard = () => {
    return orders.map(order => (
        <Card size="small" key={order.key} actions={[ <Text strong className="card-action-text" onClick={() => toggleMaxHeight(order.key)} > Expand/collapse </Text>]} bordered={false} className="order-card">
            <Card.Grid className="order-info-title" hoverable={false}>Table 1</Card.Grid>
            <Card.Grid className="order-info-title" hoverable={false}>Waiting time</Card.Grid>
            <div className={ "order-items-container" }>
                <Card.Grid className="order-items" hoverable={false}>
                    {/* Kitchen order lines */}
                </Card.Grid>
                <Card.Grid className="order-items" hoverable={false}>
                    {/* Bar order lines */}
                </Card.Grid>
            </div>
        </Card>
    ));
}
```

When the user clicks the action button to expand/collapse, i should set the div (of that order) maxHeight like they did on js on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapsible_animate), but in React.

```
if (div.style.maxHeight){ //User wants to collapse
    div.style.maxHeight = null;
} else { //User wants to expand
    div.style.maxHeight = div.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153599/reactjs-get-height-of-an-element) for getting the height, but I have multiple divs (one for each order) and the user expands and collapses any div he wants and individually.

Comment: the "react way" of doing is assign a ref to each card (the div that you want to get height)  ref.current.clientHeight. to set you need to do via state.